# How can pass mode cors to fetch in typescript?

Tags: typescript, google-api, fetch

I'm trying to do fetch in this google api 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json' with the following code, but i received cors error, I already try to put mode: 'cors', but typescript complains that string is not a RequestMode. Can you suggest something to fix this.

```
const headers = new Headers();
headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

const init = {
    method: HTTP_METHODS.POST,
    headers
};
const response await fetch(URL, init);
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a *response* header, not a request header. You are gaining nothing by putting it into the request. Your server must support CORS. In any case, the answer lies [in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_your_own_request_object).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare the type of `init` so that TypeScript can infer it to have the correct string-typed members:

```
const init: RequestInit = {...};
```

Better yet, just pass the object directly to `fetch()` instead of having a variable.